# Use Siri to play currently selected podcast in Overcast

Tags: siri, ios

Is it possible to use Siri to play the podcast that's currently open in Overcast? Saying "Hey Siri, play Overcast" opens the app, but doesn't start playing the audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Overcast 5 (released in 2018), Siri commands are now supported. To enable, go to Overcast.app ➡️ Settings ➡️ Siri Shortcuts. Then, for example, you'll be able to say *Hey Siri, Overcast play* to play the currently selected podcast. ([Source](https://sixcolors.com/post/2018/09/overcast-5-adds-siri-shortcuts-watch-playback-and-search/))

Bonus:

After Overcast is playing audio, you can use the OS-supplied Siri commands  for AirPlay to send audio to another output device. Example: *Hey Siri, play this in the Living Room* ([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209464)) It's annoying that you have to wait until your podcast is playing, and then speak over it to change output, but as of December 2021, Overcast does not support compound commands to both start playing a podcast and specify an output.

Answer (score -1):

As of now Overcast does not have support for Siri functions.